# Variable definition, beginner assist

Tags: c++

Having trouble understanding what the integers n and k are used for in the raiseToPower function. Mostly when the function is defined. I understand how when it is called it pauses main function in a way, but how are the variables n and k a factor in it?

`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "simpio.h"
#include <string>

int raiseToPower(int n, int k);
//This created a variable called raiseToPower
//It has 2 integers that it can call upon, n and k
//This makes it possible for the function to be used without a definiton in the main


int main(){
//Indicates main is a integer

int limit;

//Limit is now a variable that can hold integers

cout << "This program lists powers of two." << endl;

//Tell the user that this is what the program does

cout << "Enter exponent limit: ";

//No endl, so that the user can input something

cin >> limit;

//This lets the user input a integer, and store it in limit

for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {

    //creates a for loop that will do the action till it completes its work

    //While i = 0, and it is less then or equal to limit, add 1 to i

        cout << "2 to the " << i << " = " << raiseToPower(2, i) << endl;

}

return 0;

}

int raiseToPower(int n, int k) {
//creates variablee result that holds a integers, and in this case 1

    int result = 1;

// a for loop so that the

    for (int i=0; i < k; i++) {

       result *= n;

}

return result;
}`

Most of my problem is just in the above part right here. The function definition. I cant understand where n and k are used in here

Comment: You should read a decent C++ book, or some basic C++ tutorial on functions.

Comment: `k` used in the exit condition here `for (int i=0; i < k; i++)` and `n` is one operand in a multiplication here:  `result *= n;`

Comment: At least for me, it's hard to understand what exactly you don't understand. *"I cant understand where n and k are used"* - Right there, no? `for (int i=0; i < k; i++) {result *= n;}`.

Comment: So your question is that you don't understand what a function parameter is?

Comment: you don't understand the concept of a function and calling a function OR you don't understand the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raiseToPower` is a function that returns a value.

`n` and `k` are integer parameters passed to the `raiseToPower` function.  Where `n` is being raised to `k`.

To do this the function just multiples `n` by itself `k` times by looping from 0 to `k`-1.  This is accomplished with the line

```
result *= n
```

which can also be written as

```
result = result * n.
```